# MySQL - Set default row (which not exist) value in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to set a default value of row which does not exist in table? So I need to create a fictional row.

Example:

```
| ID | SOM_VAL |
| 1  | 2       |
```

And now, to get all rows from SQL, where ID = 1, the statement will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE ID = 1;
```

and the result will be:

```
| ID | SOM_VAL |
| 1  | 2       |
```

I want to set fictional row with something default value to get this result:

```
| ID | SOM_VAL | FICTIONAL_VAL |
| 1  | 2       | 3             |
```

but the `FICTIONAL_VAL` does not exist in SQL table, so I need to define name and value of fictional row in `SELECT` statement, something like that:

```
SELECT *, fictional_val = 3
FROM `table`
WHERE id = 1;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: sure use `SELECT *, 3 fictional_col FROM table WHERE id = 1`

Comment: you are welcome :)